# How long did Frodo and Sam take to reach Mount Doom?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

How long did it take for Frodo and Sam to get from the Shire to Mount Doom in Mordor and drop the Ring in?

Comment: If you go by the extended edition, about nine and a half hours.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Frodo and Sam left *Bag End* the day after Frodo and Bilbo's birthday, September 23 3018 TA (exactly 17 years *after* the night of Bilbo's disappearance). The destruction of the Ring at Mt Doom took place March 25 3019. So the entire journey took about 6 months. But note that this included about 2 months spent in Rivendell, and a month in Lothlorien. See the [LotR Timeline](http://www.lordotrings.com/books/timeline.asp) (lordotrings.com) and [Timeline of Arda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda) (Wikipedia) for more details. Many of the dates can also be found in the appendices of LotR.